# hide button with class x on document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendo Custom Command in my application and i want to display Add button with each record and when user click on it, program replace Add button with remove... i haven't managed that in document.ready but managed to do in  $(document.body) ... now i want to hide remove button that is with class k-grid-remove but i am struggling to do like

```
$("td >.k-grid-Remove").hide(); in document.ready(function()...
```

### grid code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DatabaseLayer.TableMappings.FeeZone>()
.Name("FeeZoneGrid_02")
.Columns(columns =>
{
  columns.Bound(c => c.FeeZoneID);
  columns.Bound(c => c.FeeZoneDescription);
  columns.Command(
    command =>
      {

          command.Custom("Add").SendDataKeys(true).Click("AddFeeZoneToScheme");

          command.Custom("Remove").SendDataKeys(true).Click("RemoveFeeZoneFromScheme");
      }
     );
   })

 .Selectable(selectable => selectable
     .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
     .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllFreeZone", "Qualification"))
     .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.FeeZoneID))
)
)
```

### HTML output

```
 ........
<td role="gridcell">

<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Add" href="#"></a>
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-Remove" href="#"></a>

</td>
```

### JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document.body).on('click', 'td > .k-grid-Add', function () {

        $(this).hide();

        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-Remove").show();
    });

    $(document.body).on('click', 'td > .k-grid-Remove', function () {

        $(this).hide();

        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-Add").show();
    });
});

</script>
```

what I am trying to achieve is when user click add button it replaces with remove button and vice verse... at the movement I am displaying both in grid custom command

Many Thanks

Comment: Where is your `$(document).ready`?

Comment: i have tried in $(document).ready but it doesn't work... but it works with  $(document.body)

Comment: That is not the same. Have you tried `$(document).ready(function() {  $("td >.k-grid-Remove").hide(); });`

Comment: i have tried but like i say it didn't work

Comment: Just to be clear.. you want all `td >.k-grid-Remove` to be hidden on document ready? Why don't you add a CSS style for it?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.x').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Whoever rated down: Read the FAQ for 'vote down', it's for extreme bad answers, AND this is just an alternative. So, please vote up, it's even your reputation.

Comment: it wasn't me ... but i make ur ranking up many thanks atleast you are trying to help

Comment: the `.x` could be everything, so he wants to hide and show buttons? Yes what will work.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the answer

```
           command.Custom("Remove").SendDataKeys(true).Click("RemoveFeeZoneFromScheme").HtmlAttributes(new { style="display: none;"});
```